# JavaScriptSerializer with Razor and ASPX engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, razor, jsonserializer

I am serializing a list object using the `JavaScriptSerializer` and assigning the result to a javascript object but when i use the aspx engine the quotes in the json string are considered as double quotes and working correct but when using razor engine the double quotes are printed as `&quot;` and through exception.

How to resolve this?

My sample code.

ASPX:

```
var data = <%=JsonConverter.ConvertDataTabletoString()%>
var data = [{"No":"1","Name":"John"},{"No":"2","Name":"Smith"},  {"No":"3","Name":"Tomps"},{"No":"4","Name":"Hanar"},{"No":"5","Name":"Reek"}]`
```

Razor:

```
var data = @JsonConverter.ConvertDataTabletoString()
var data = [{&quot;No&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Heer&quot;},{&quot;No&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Heer&quot;},{&quot;No&quot;:1,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Heer&quot;}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Html.Raw() to print out the code in the Razor view. That will stop the code from being HTML-escaped.

Eg:

```
@Html.Raw(JsonConverter.ConvertDataTabletoString())
```

Comment: Hi buddy Thanks its worked... but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: For Razor pages, I haven't found a better way. Remember, Razor was meant for HTML pages, so for that purpose printing out HTML-escaped characters is actually helpful.